# Is it possible to draw route between two location without using Direction API

Tags: java, android-studio

I would like to ask is it possible to draw route between two location on Map without using Direction API?

Comment: You need to specify what "Map" you mean. Is it part of a library? What libraries are you using?

Comment: @JayC667 Im using a Google Map

Comment: @Drwin, can you improve the question, You are using Google Maps to show the map tiles and you want to draw routes between two locations without using Google Maps?

Comment: @carpinchosaurio I use MAPS sdk for android, I mean can I draw a route without using Direction API? sorry for bad english .